# Page model imports

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I'm writing tests using TestCafe and, as my page models grow, my imports are consuming a lot of space. So it would be good to have the imports in a concise way.

Page Model 1:

```
export ClassA {...}

export ClassB {...}
```

Page Model 2:

```
export Class C {...}

export Class D {...}
```

Then on my test file, I'm using

```
import { ClassA, ClassB, ClassC, ClassD } from './pages'
```

It's clear that when the number of classes gets larger, my import will become large.

Is it possible to use a wildcard `*` in this case? What's the recommended way?

```
import * from 'page_model1'
import * from 'page_model2'
...
```

or

```
import * from './pages'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that they will be accesible using the following piece of code

```
import * as Pages from './pages';

// Then used it as this
Pages.ClassA;
```